# How can I handle storing Firebase notifications for offline access in my chat app?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on implementing a **chat application** using **Firebase Cloud Messaging** and facing difficulties architecting it to handle offline scenarios.

Here's what I aim to achieve: When my app is closed or not running (even in the background) and the internet connection is off, upon receiving a new notification from a sender, I want to cache or store it in the database. Later, when I open my app without an internet connection, I should be able to see all the received messages.

Here's what I've implemented so far:

MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt

```
val TAG = "FSNotifi"
private val PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile"

class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            editor.putString("FSNoti", it.body.toString())
            editor.apply()
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Despite this setup, the message doesn't seem to be stored in **SharedPreferences**. I'm seeking guidance on how to properly achieve this task. Is there a better approach or a step I might be missing in implementing this offline message storage functionality using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**PS**: I found answer of my question

Userful Link: [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase?rq=2)

Comment: I think you should use ```Room``` Database for storing it offline for later use.

Comment: You are right @ChiragThummar but I will store in room once it gets stored in sharedpreference

Comment: No when notification is received you can save data in room and you can use it later as you wish

Comment: @ChiragThummar I meant to say just for testing I am storing in sharedpreference

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).